# Dropdown Sidebar Menu Items in Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

In the Laravel Backpack docs they show an image that appears to have dropdown menus for the sidebar navigation menu, but I can't find anywhere that says how to use them. Is there a built in way or do I have to write my own styles?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `resources/views/vendor/backpack/base/inc/sidebar.blade.php` you can add your own menu-items. Using `.treeview` and `.treeview-menu` you can make those items expandable:

See also [the source code](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/Demo/blob/master/resources/views/vendor/backpack/base/inc/sidebar.blade.php#L38:L46) of that image.

```html
<li class="treeview">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-key"></i> <span>Roles & Permissions</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
  <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="{{ url(config('backpack.base.route_prefix', 'admin') . '/role') }}"><span>Roles</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="{{ url(config('backpack.base.route_prefix', 'admin') . '/permission') }}"><span>Permissions</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: @Victor I'm new to Backpack. How do we get vendor views into our 'resources/views' folder, should they be copied manually?

Comment: The new link (source code) for the demo sidebar is https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/Demo/blob/master/resources/views/vendor/backpack/base/inc/sidebar_content.blade.php

Answer (score 4):

As [Oscar Torres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9252765/oscar-torres) pointed out, the new demo source for a nested menu lives [here](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/Demo/blob/master/resources/views/vendor/backpack/base/inc/sidebar_content.blade.php).

Backpack now uses Bootstrap's `nav-dropdown` class(es) to achieve these results:

```html
<li class="nav-item nav-dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="nav-icon la la-group"></i> Authentication</a>
    <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ backpack_url('user') }}"><i class="nav-icon la la-user"></i> <span>Users</span></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ backpack_url('role') }}"><i class="nav-icon la la-group"></i> <span>Roles</span></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ backpack_url('permission') }}"><i class="nav-icon la la-key"></i> <span>Permissions</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work anymore with latest backpack. + laravel

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Backpack version 6.x. To show a dropdown menu, with elements, you can use the menu-dropdown and menu-dropdown-item components:

```
<x-backpack::menu-dropdown title="Authentication" icon="la la-group">
    <x-backpack::menu-dropdown-item title="Users" icon="la la-user" :link="backpack_url('user')" />
    <x-backpack::menu-dropdown-item title="Roles" icon="la la-group" :link="backpack_url('role')" />
    <x-backpack::menu-dropdown-item title="Permissions" icon="la la-key" :link="backpack_url('permission')" />
</x-backpack::menu-dropdown>
```

More info [here](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/base-components#menu-dropdown-menu-dropdown-item)